# Cannot assign value to the outer function variable in then function in dart

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

I'm getting data from REST API.

And check if my data which gotten from api is not null.

```
fun(order,phone){
bool isNotNull;
// repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone") is function which get data from Rest api
     repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone").then((value) {
       if (value != null) {
         isNotNull=true;
         _showOrder.sink.add(value);
       } else {
         print("ELSE B:${isNotNull}");
         isNotNull = false;
         print("ELSE A:${isNotNull}");
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Not found");
       }
     });
   }
```

My **isNotNull** *variable* is always **null**.
It is not waiting to be assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid callback hell, try this:

```dart
Future<void> fun(order, phone) async {
    final value = await repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone");
    value != null ? _showOrder.sink.add(value) : Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Not found");
  }
```

Comment: I little changed this code to also add Navigator.push()

  final value = await repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone");
      if(value != null) {
        _showOrder.sink.add(value);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => OrderStatusPage()));
      }else Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Not found");
But now my stream does not get data

Comment: By the way, you should not use Streams directly, prefer [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) library

Comment: The architecture  is not flutter_bloc it is just bloc @AndreyGritsay

Comment: when i used then it add data to stream, but in your way it not

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setState` for it to work..

```
fun(order,phone){
bool isNotNull;
// repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone") is function which get data from Rest api
     repository.myOrder(order, "998$phone").then((value) {
       if (value != null) {
        setState((){
          isNotNull=true;
         });
         _showOrder.sink.add(value);
       } else {
         print("ELSE B:${isNotNull}");
         setState((){
          isNotNull=false;
         });
         print("ELSE A:${isNotNull}");
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Not found");
       }
     });
   }
```

Hope it works for you..

Comment: there is not setState function @srikanth7785

Comment: I didn't get you..!?there's no `setState` function..!?

Comment: Im using Bloc Design pattern which means my ui and controller are separated
@srikanth7785

Comment: Ohh..okay..I didn't know that..you should have mentioned that in your question..I guess..!